# interest of something?

Tags: meaning

We know the meaning of *interest **in** something*; But what does **interest of life** mean in the following context?

> Security alone might produce a smug and stationary society; it demands creativeness as its counterpart, in order to keep alive the adventure and **interest of life**, and the movement toward perpetually new and better things.

Comment: It's not a combination I've ever heard used.  It's pretty much nonexistent on Ngram.

Comment: It's the possesive *of*. It means the same as "life's adventure and interest".

Comment: @Andrew, this is written in 1917.

Comment: I'm almost sure that `adventure` and `interest` are possessions (not sure if that's how I should call it) **of** the subject **life**. Like in "life's adventure and interest".

Comment: Hmm... I was too slow. The Photon measures up to its name...

Comment: @ThePhoton, so you think "interest" means _advantage_ here?

Comment: No. Your quote says that interest and adventure are two things that life has.

Comment: @ThePhoton, if I've understood you correctly, "the quality of exciting curiosity or holding the attention" is the appropriate dictionary definition for "interest" here.